# What kind of Magento (2.3) Installation is Best for Future any Updates?

Tags: upgrade, installation, debugging, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

For further future updates what kind of installation is best  , **Command-line installation** (or) **Setup Wizard installation**

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your question for the further future updates what kind of installation is best.

Magento updates are not depend on how you installed magento by CLI or Setup wizard you always getting all the updates from magento.

But if you want fast and heckless installation You should practice to using command line. So it will make installation more easier.

Because when you installing via setup wizard sometimes due to server request limitation it wil stuck after some percentage of installation and you have to try another time. So go with CLI. and any of the method want affect in magento updates.

Hope it will be helpful.